# Can't upgrade kernel in xenial

Tags: 16.04, grub2, kernel

I have a problem with one server. Some time ago there was installed trusty, then I upgrade it to xenial. The problem is that it looks like he doesn't want newer kernel ;)

```
% uname -a
```

Linux 36monkeys 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

hm, 3.11? But why?

```
% apt list --installed|grep linux

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

console-setup-linux/xenial-updates,now 1.108ubuntu15.2 all [installed,automatic]
libselinux1/xenial,now 2.4-3build2 i386 [installed]
linux-base/xenial,now 4.0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
linux-firmware/xenial-updates,now 1.157.4 all [installed,automatic]
linux-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.45.48 i386 [installed]
linux-headers-4.4.0-38/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-38.57 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-38.57 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.4.0-45/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-45.66 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-45.66 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.45.48 i386 [installed]
linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-38.57 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-45.66 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-38.57 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-45.66 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.45.48 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-libc-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-45.66 i386 [installed,automatic]
util-linux/xenial-updates,now 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1 i386 [installed]
```

There is nothing related to 3.11... 
There was menu.lst in /boot/grub with entries related to 3.11, I removed this file.

There is nothing related with 3.11 in /boot or /etc/default/grub, `/initrd.img` points to `boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic`, `/vmlinuz` points to `boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic` etc.

What can I do to upgrade kernel to 4.4.x?

BTW, after every change I remembered about `update-grub`, sometimes also I was doing `update-initramfs` and rebooted server...

Comment: is it possible that /boot lives on its own partition but you're not mounting it after booting?

Comment: @FlorianHeinle `mount` doesn't show nothing related to this mountpoint, and I didn't do nothing special with partitions. In fact, I just use standard droplet on Digitalocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You mentioned that you're using a Digitalocean Droplet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840736/cant-upgrade-kernel-in-xenial?noredirect=1#comment1286927_840736). Their method of kernel deployment differs slightly from a system running on bare metal

[Refer to Digital Ocean's documentation for kernel upgrades](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel).

To sum up some gotchas:

- if you're using a kernel provided by the control panel, you'll have to make your changes there, too.
- reboot of the droplet alone does not upgrade the kernel, only shutdown does
- you can select a special `GrubLoader` kernel to delegate kernel selection back to the guest operaing system.

Comment: Great! It was that, I didn't noticed that DO has this kind of feature... Thank you very much! Works great now.